# Do you lose one point of reputation when you down vote community wiki? Meta?

Tags: discussion

Do you lose one point of reputation when you down vote community wiki?  Meta?

I know that you do for "regular questions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Bicycles [FAQ](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq):

> please note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation.

...and from the meta.bicycles [FAQ](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the parent website; your reputation is the same as your reputation on the parent website, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way.

(The only exception to that last part is reputation on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), a special case.)

Comment: In case the first quoted FAQ is unclear: voting on CW posts doesn't affect reputation in any way, up or down for either person.  Votes on CW still affect badges.